# getting EntityCommandExecutionException when I run the webapp connecting to duplicate db on different server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, exception, web-config, connection-string

I need to test a web application.So I copied the database file and connected to  the dulicate databse on different sql server.. The application is running fine when I connected to the live database but when I connected to the duplicate database on my server.. it is throwing entity command execution exception. I changed the connection string details in the webapp( source,username, pwd) and also connected in vs. Did I miss anything(in connecting to database file) ? I searched a lot.. but couldn't figure out.. what was it I am doing wrong which throws exception ?  I made it run once, but it didn't work again after please throw some light on how could I approach it...?

Comment: You should probably share the details of the exception you're getting. That might help others to be able to suggest to you a solution.

Comment: hi sachin, it just says entity command execution exception.please let me know what  details would be required  ? However, it works perfectly fine with the live db. So I think there should be  something wrong connecting with the duplicate database..

Comment: regarding exception it just says this...........................  as inner exception {"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."}